# How do I check if a string contains another string in Objective-C? String contains URLs

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

If im using URLs for string compare it is not working for me check with below code for that

```
 NSString *string = @"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3I-YwybNGiA";

    if ([string containsString:@"www.youtube.com/watchv=3I-YwybNGiA"]) 
      { 
        NSLog(@"string contains www.youtube.com/watchv=3I-YwybNGiA!");

      } else {

        NSLog(@"string does not contain www.youtube.com/watchv=3I-YwybNGiA");

       }
```

Comment: `watch?v=3I` vs `watchv=3I`, there is a **?**...

Comment: @Kamran `contains != isEqual`

Comment: @mag_zbc Ahh. sorry! thought the other way. I think we both need some sleep :)

Comment: #Thanks I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In original string

> watch?v=3I-YwybNGiA

In substring you're searching

> watchv=3I-YwybNGiA

There's `?` missing